# jQuery detect programatic change to field

Tags: jquery

I have a hidden field called `#myHiddenField` say.

The content of this field is programatically changed at various places.

I'd like a method that detects that change.  The change event won't fire unless I type into the field but this is impossible.

Is there a jQuery way to detect programatic content change in a field?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You should be able to trigger the change event with:

```
$('#myHiddenField').change();
```

OR

```
$('#myHiddenField').trigger('change');
```

Of course this will require the block of code responsible for updating the filed to make one of those calls after it has done its work.

Comment: Have moved the place where the field is being set into its own function and used the trigger command.  Works like a treat thank you

Comment: @griegs Hey, that kind of sounds like... my first suggestion :P

Comment: @alex, yeah ok +1 but i think this one shows it better for future users.  :)

Answer (score 7):

The DOM cannot detect the programmatic raising of events. I actually ran into this yesterday. I don't remember where I read it, but the solution was to actually call `.trigger()` on the jQuery element. [jQuery Doc](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

Answer (score 6):

**Case 1:** 
You want to change the value programmatically yourself and just want to dispatch an event when the value is changed.

```
$('#myfield').text('New value');
//$('#myfield').val('New value');
$('#myfield').trigger('change');
```

**Case 2:**

Suppose, you want to detect the programmatic change to a field which is not written by you. So, there is no way you can trigger 'change' event.

In this case, Use 'DOMSubtreeModified' to detect programmatic changes to descendant elements of a parent element.

Example:

```
<div id="product-addons-total">
    <div id="total_price">200</div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery('#product-addons-total').on("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
        console.log('content changed');
        //tamp_price_change_handler();
    });
});
```

Now, if the value of the "total_price" changes somehow programmatically, it will fire "DOMSubtreeModified" event.
   Example:

```
jQuery('#total_price').text('300');
```

**Caution for Case 2:** **DOMSubtreeModified** can create an **infinite loop** and greatly **degrade performance**. Instead, it is encouraged to use **MutationObserver**.

Example with MutationObserver:

```
// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    console.log(mutation.type);        
  });    
});

// Let's configure the observer
var config = { childList: true, subtree:true, attributes: true, characterData: true,
    characterDataOldValue: true, attributeOldValue: true };
//Let's get a node.
var target = jQuery('#product-addons-total').get(0); 
// Let's pass the target and configuration to the observe function.
observer.observe(target, config);
```

**Case 3:**

The above ways can detect a change in the DOM. But if you want to change the value of an input field programmatically, then these events won't fire. In that case, the only way is to **trigger an event manually**.
So, first change the value of an input field and then trigger an event manually.

```
$('#inputfield').val(456465).trigger('change');

//Now the change event will fire.
$('#inputfield').on('change', function() {  
    console.log('input filed has been changed');
});
```

Comment: It appears this doesn't work for changing value of inputs.

Comment: @dlsso Yes, these events (both DOMSubtreeModified and MutationObserver) can only detect changes in the DOM. Such as when a node is modified, a node is added or deleted, an attribute is changed, etc. But when you programmatically change the value of an input field these events will not notice a change in the DOM. In this case, you will need to manually fire an event after changing the value of an input field programmatically. Such as ```$('#inputfield').val(456465).trigger('change'); ```Then handle event with ```$('#inputfield').on('change', function(){ console.log('changed'); });```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the value using .val() in jQuery doesn't trigger a change event so you'll have to use .change() or .trigger('change') to trigger an change event. You can choose to use either .change(function() { ... }) or .on('change', function() { ... } to detect the change event to the field.

```
$('#myHiddenField').change(function() {
    alert('content changed to: ' + $('#myHiddenField').val());
});

$('#btnChange').click(function() {
    $('#myHiddenField').val("new content");
    $('#myHiddenField').change();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qeg5of2a/1/

or

```
$('#myHiddenField').on('change', function() {
    alert('content changed to: ' + $('#myHiddenField').val());
});

$('#btnChange').click(function() {
    $('#myHiddenField').val("new content");
    $('#myHiddenField').trigger('change');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qeg5of2a/2/

.change is just shortcut for .on('change', handler) and .trigger('change') so either is fine

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the `change` event to fire when the field changed by Blazor of the .NET framework, but alternatively you could redefine the `value` property of the input field:

```
Object.defineProperty($('#myHiddenField')[0], 'value', {
    get() { debugger; return "1"; },
    set(value) { debugger; }
})
```