# Detect input value change with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

This question has been made in several places but I have not found a great answer. I want to detect an input (text) value change. The value is changed via pure JavaScript with no frameworks (I can't access this) so the solution can't be modify the `val()` function of jQuery to trigger an event. Events won't work as you know. The only solution that actually works is

`setInterval(function() { ObserveInputValue($('#input_id').val()); }, 100);`

but I want to find something different without using a `setInterval`

Comment: You can use javascript event for input.
change, keyup, keydown, keypress

Comment: @RadonirinaMaminiaina: a programmatic value-change ("*the value is changed via...[JavaScript]...*") doesn't fire those events.

Comment: Please clarify. Input value of what? A text field? Do check out existing answers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481152/how-to-detect-a-textboxs-content-has-changed

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200358/jquery-detect-programatic-change-to-field

Comment: @SamwellTarly yeah I checked all those, and as I said in the post, programmatic value-change via JS wont trigger any event.

Comment: @RadonirinaMaminiaina programmatic value-change via JS wont trigger any event and as I said I can't access the code responsible for updating the filed

Comment: If the value of your input is changed, the change event will triggered. Have you try it?

Comment: @RadonirinaMaminiaina if the value is changed programatically it wont trigger any events, so `Change` event, or `Input` event wont work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you listen / detect changes to an input value - when the input value is changed via JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55033836/how-do-you-listen-detect-changes-to-an-input-value-when-the-input-value-is-c)

Answer (score 0):

As David Thomas says, changing the value via javascript doesn't fire the onchange event... Therefore your javascript function needs to call the element.onchange() event once it has completed.

Comment: and that is the issue, I don't have access to the js function changing the value

Answer (score -5):

You can write your own JavaScript function to listen to onChange() event using jQuery and then monitor if the value has changed or not.

The Code using JavaScript is as follows:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="checkThis" placeholder="Enter Something Here...">

<script type="text/javascript">
      $("#checkThis").on("change", function() {
        // Press `F12` on Chrome or `Ctrl+Shift+S` on Firefox to view output in browser console
        console.log($(this).val());
      });
</script>
```