# How do you listen / detect changes to an input value - when the input value is changed via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, autocomplete

I've got an `input` with Google AutoComplete connected.

When the user moves up and down through the `seachResults` the value of the input is changed dynamically via JavaScript.

I'd like to capture the value that is in the input at any given time.

I've tried `onChange` and `onInput` but since no event is getting fired, and the `value` of the DOM Node is not getting set - there are no updates.

**How do you detect changes to the `input` that are dynamically updated via JavaScript**?

Comment: `the value of the DOM Node is not getting set` Wait, is the value being changed via Javascript, or not? Title implies it is, but that line there implies that it's not?

Comment: Make no mistake - the value of the input does change - I believe via Google - but the value attribute does not update unless an event is fired. For example, if onBlur or onClick is fired - the value attribute updates but when the results are changed via google autoComplete - it does not.

Comment: The value *attribute* shouldn't change, though the value *property* should. How are you determining that it doesn't update, are you just listening for an event and not seeing one that triggers the listener? A live snippet (or a link) that illustrates the behavior would probably clear things up significantly

Comment: Potato? Potawto? What do you mean by property? The DOM Node of the input has a value attribute. When I'm watching the DOM using the browser inspector the value does not change unless an event is fired.

Answer (score 20):

The `.value` *attribute* will only change if the script-writer has called `setAttribute('value'` to set the new value, which is quite an odd thing to do. In almost all situations, I would expect the value to be set by assigning to the `value` property directly, eg:

```
input.value = 'foo';
```

Calling `setAttribute` will indeed show a change in the inspected DOM *attribute*, eg:

```
<input value="somevalue">
```

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
input.setAttribute('value', 'foo');
console.log(input.outerHTML);
```

```html
<input>
```

But just assigning to the `.value` *property* of the element will not result in such a change:

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
input.value = 'foo';
console.log(input.outerHTML);
```

```html
<input>
```

Assigning to the `.value` actually invokes a *setter function* on `HTMLInputElement.prototype`:

```js
console.log(HTMLInputElement.prototype.hasOwnProperty('value'));
```

You can *shadow* this by putting a getter/setter for `value` directly on the element itself, with the setter invoking your own function, allowing you to listen for changes:

```js
const { get, set } = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(HTMLInputElement.prototype, 'value');
const input = document.querySelector('input');
Object.defineProperty(input, 'value', {
  get() {
    return get.call(this);
  },
  set(newVal) {
    console.log('New value assigned to input: ' + newVal);
    return set.call(this, newVal);
  }
});


// example of autocomplete trying to change the input value:
input.value = 'foo';
```

```html
<input>
```

Comment: this looks promising. I will give this a shot :)

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not :/

Comment: Can you post the code you're using so there's a [MCVE] to debug? As you can see from the live snippets (just press "Run code snippet"), the Javascript-initiated changes to the `.value` of the inputs look to be intercepted and observed as desired.

Comment: The shadow getter/setter worked perfectly for me. This helped me hack around a bug nicely.

Comment: Nailed it! the overriding of get and set is the way to go if you can not trigger the evens manually using JavaScript when changing the value.

Answer (score 3):

Consider creating and triggering input events

```
var event = new Event('input', {
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true,
});
```

then

```
myelement.dispatchEvent(event);
```

**[more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35659430/how-do-i-programmatically-trigger-an-input-event-without-jquery)**

Answer (score 1):

You can run this after programmatically changing the .value

```
document.querySelector('#element-id').dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
```

Listen for a value change:

```
document.querySelector('#element-id').addEventListener('input', function() {
  console.log(this.value);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can start events manually with JS.

```
<script>
const my_input = document.getElementById("my_input");
my_input.onchange=function(){console.log("changed!");};
const event = new Event('change');
my_input.dispatchEvent(event);//console writes "changed!" now.
//"event" can be reused like: 
//my_input2.dispatchEvent(event);
//my_input3.dispatchEvent(event);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Other solutions above require listening to all inputs or all of the DOM, but here is a different solution designed to detect a value change of a specific element:

You can use a setInterval.  I needed to observe a specific DOM element value changing and I was able to target the specific elementID with the following:

```
var watchID ;
var el = document.getElementById('elementID') ;
var oldValue = el.value ;
var watchCount = 0 ;  // create a built in timeout function
watchID = setInterval(function() {
  watchCount++ ;
  if (el.value != oldValue) {
    console.log("Element Changed:" +el.value) ;
    ... do something ...
    clearInterval(watchID) ;
  }
  // 30 second timeout
  if (watchCount == 60) {
    console.log("Interval Timeout")          
    clearInterval(watchID) ;
  }
},500) ;  // execute every 1/2 second for 30 seconds
```

In my case, I had a complex file download that needed a bit of a different hacky solution and the above worked without any eventListeners or other more complex solutions that monitored everything (like: `MutationObserver`).  Of course you don't need the custom timeout...but if you don't, you may want a more friendly solution than mine.  A continuous interval could strain resources.