# Global variable not working as an input value

Tags: javascript, html, variables, global-variables

I am a JavaScript beginner, I am stuck with a problem regarding variables.

I wrote this code :

```
var acNo = document.getElementById("ac").value;

function doSomething(){
    alert(acNo);
}
```

The output is: `undefined`

But when I did this :

```
var acNo = 3
```

The output is 3

Html code :
(This is a very big project so that's why I cant share much code, but I am sharing the HTML code related to this script)

```
<td>A/c</td>
            <td> <input type="number" name="" id="ac"></td>
            <td> <input type="number" name="" id="acHour"></td>
```

Can you please tell me how can I fix it while keeping the variable global only.

Comment: You will have to show your HTML too, mate

Comment: I have edited the question and put the code too

Answer (score 1):

Try defining acNo after the document has fully loaded, or within the function.

**Solution 1:**

```
let acNo;

window.onload = () => {
 acNo = document.getElementById("ac").value;
}

function doSomething() {
 alert(acNo);
}
```

**Solution 2:**

```
funtion doSomething() {
    alert(document.getElementById("ac").value)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A way you can go to check that is by opening the dev tools of your browser and running your `document.getElementById` in the console.

You will be able to see everything about the element and what properties it has. For example, you might want to check `innerHTML` instead of `value` depending on your element type.

Answer (score 0):

I think the value is only set in the beginning and not when you run `doSomething` later. If you want to have the value globally, have a global variable and keep updating it when you call `doSomething`.

```
var acNo = document.getElementById("ac").value;

function doSomething(){
acNo = document.getElementById("ac").value;
alert(acNo);
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to use the variable without assigning it in the function scope?

Comment: Then you have to listen to the change of the input value. Using the attribute `onChange`. Like : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55033836/how-do-you-listen-detect-changes-to-an-input-value-when-the-input-value-is-c

Comment: But that is something you can find on SO easily.