# What is the alternative to on('input' , to track the indirect change in textbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table having 15 rows of text boxes with class `foo`.

If I write something suppose in the 5th text box I want the same text to be written in all subsequent boxes i.e the 6th, 7th, 8th ... 15th.

The following code has done the job but only when I change value by clicking on input field. But I want the code to work even if value of input field is changed indirectly say by another text box (suppose I have another single textbox and if I write any number there the content of 5th textbox is replaced by the sum of 5th textbox and single textbox).

How to modify the code? I have tried `on('change'` in place of `on('input'`, but get no result.

```
jQuery($ => {
  $('.foo').on('input', e => {
    $(e.target).closest('tr').nextAll('tr').find('.foo').val(e.target.value);
  });
});
```

Comment: I take it the `input` is a `type=checkbox` or `type=radio` ?

Comment: How does a textbox change an input? Are you doing this through JavaScript or browser magic that I don't know about?

Comment: input type="textbox"

Comment: JavaScript events like `input` and `change` are **not** triggered when the actions they represent are performed from within JavaScript.

Comment: suppose I have another single textbox and if I write any number there the content of 5th textbox is replaced by the sum of 5th textbox and single textbox.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you listen / detect changes to an input value - when the input value is changed via javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55033836/how-do-you-listen-detect-changes-to-an-input-value-when-the-input-value-is-c)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `jQuery.trigger()` on the 5th textbox to trigger the `input` event. So that the subsequent boxes will be updated, too.

Let say we have the 5th textbox and another textbox, and we want to make

> the content of 5th textbox is replaced by the sum of 5th textbox and single textbox.

It's not simply set `5thTextbox.value += anotherTextbox.value` on `input` event. Because if you input any word, sentence that has more than 2 chars the thing will be messed up. For example:

- `5thTextbox` value: **123**
- Input **456** to `anotherTextbox`. Then the `input` event would update the `5thTextbox` to 123445456. And that's not what you want.

So I make a simple condition, whenever you input the second char into the `anotherTextbox`. We just have to remove the value of the `anotherTextbox` at the end of the `5thTextbox`. I use `regex` to achieve that

```js
let startInput = false;
$(document).ready(() => {
  $("table input").on('input', (e) => {
    updatetTextOfNextInputs(e.currentTarget);
  });

  $("#another-input").on("focus blur", (e) => {
    // clear the another input
    e.currentTarget.value = "";
    startInput = false;
  })

  $("#another-input").on('input', (e) => {
    let fifthInputEl = $("table input")[4];
    if (startInput) {
      // The value of the 5th inbox already contains the first char of the another inbox, you have to remove that before sum the new one
      // Use regex to replace
      // have to remove the last char of the value first, using slice()
      var previousValue = e.currentTarget.value.slice(0, -1);
      // use regex to remove value of another textbox out of the end of 5th textbox
      const regex = new RegExp(`${previousValue}$`);
      fifthInputEl.value = fifthInputEl.value.replace(regex, '');
    }
    // input the value at the end
    fifthInputEl.value += `${e.currentTarget.value}`;
    // after input the first char, turn this flag to true
    startInput = true;
    // finally trigger the input to make change to other textboxes
    $(fifthInputEl).trigger('input');
  });
})

function updatetTextOfNextInputs(inputEl) {
  $(inputEl).closest('tr').nextAll('tr').find('input').val(inputEl.value);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="display: flex">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <h3>5th Input</h3><input type="text">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <div class="another-input-wrapper">
    <h2 style="margin-top:100px">Another input</h2>
    <input id="another-input" type="text">
  </div>
</div>
```