# detect if the textarea value is set programmetically

Tags: javascript, html

My website receives some text through API call and that value is displayed on textarea on the page.
I want to run a function to perform some tasks after the value is set to textarea. But I don't see any event triggering when setting textarea value through program.
I cannot find any related questions, solutions or articles regarding this.

Below is the demonstration of the problem I am facing.

```js
txt.onchange = () => {
  alert("textarea changed (onchange event)");
}

txt.onkeyup = () => {
  alert("textarea changed (onkeyup event)");
}

txt.onkeydown = () => {
  alert("textarea changed (onkeydown event)");
}

txt.oninput = () => {
  alert("textarea changed (oninput event)");
}

changetxt.onclick = () => {
  txt.value = "value is set programmetically.";
}
```

```html
<textarea id="txt" rows="10"></textarea>
<button id="changetxt">Update Textarea</button>
```

I want some way to detect textarea value is changed through program.

Comment: Why can't you put the code in your `onClick` event listener?

Comment: @MichaelM. can you show example?

Comment: Let's say you have a function you want to run, called `func()`. Why can't you call `func()` right after the line `txt.value = "value is set programmetically.";`

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your problem correctly would this achieve the desired result

```
const { get, set } = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(HTMLTextAreaElement.prototype, 'value');
const t = document.getElementById('txt');
Object.defineProperty(t, 'value', {
  get() {
    return get.call(this);
  },
  set(newVal) {
    console.log('Input changed');
    let result = set.call(this, newVal);
    return result;
  }
});
```

This is a modified version of https://stackoverflow.com/a/55033939/5072590

Comment: This is the only answer that actually solves the problem.

Comment: Many many thanks! Searching around the whole day for this solution. I found a few other examples with Object.defineProperty for value, but then the user input did not reflect anymore to value (get).

Also maybe a hint, if your code is doing somting witht the textarea.value then take care on the order:

`  set(newVal) {
    let result = set.call(this, newVal);
    //call function which refers to t.value....
    return result;
  }`

Answer (score -1):

is you js inside a fn that got triggered when the dom is ready? like described here?
[Vanilla JavaScript equivalent of jQuery's $.ready() - how to call a function when the page/DOM is ready for it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/vanilla-javascript-equivalent-of-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-whe)

Comment: This does not answer the question. OP wants to run code when the `<textarea>`'s value is changed programmatically, **not** when the `<textarea>` is ready for JS code to manipulate.

Comment: ut the hooks works only when dom is ready

Comment: The problem is not that the JS is being before the DOM is ready. The problem is that event listeners are not called when code is changed programmatically. You have a fundamental misunderstanding.

Comment: code changed? i understood that the CONTENT of the textarea changed - so dom elements didn’t changed - lets see what the author thinks about the answers